# How do I copy information from a text file into a table in my created database in postgresql via pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am working on windows. I have installed postgresql-12 and pgadmin-4 Now through pgadmin I have created a database and through the query tool I have punched in some syntax to create a table within the created database. The syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
    Date date NOT NULL,
    ISO varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    datenum int NOT NULL,
    DOW char(3) NOT NULL,
    DOWint smallint NOT NULL,
    Year smallint NOT NULL,
    Month smallint NOT NULL,
    DOM smallint NOT NULL,
    MonthAbbr char(3) NOT NULL,
    DOY smallint NOT NULL,
    Mondays smallint NOT NULL,
    Tuesdays smallint NOT NULL,
    Wednesdays smallint NOT NULL,
    Thursdays smallint NOT NULL,
    Fridays smallint NOT NULL,
    Saturdays smallint NOT NULL,
    Sundays smallint NOT NULL,
    NumHolidays int NOT NULL,
    HolidayName varchar(255) NULL,
    HolidayType varchar(9) NULL,
    hol_National varchar(255) NULL,
    hol_Minor varchar(255) NULL,
    hol_Christian varchar(255) NULL,
    hol_Jewish varchar(255) NULL,
    hol_Muslim varchar(255) NULL,
    hol_Chinese varchar(255) NULL,
    hol_Other varchar(255) NULL
) ;
```

Now I punch in the following piece of code to fill the created table with data:

```
COPY Calendar FROM 'C:\Users\LENOVO\SQLbook_database\Calendar.txt'
    WITH HEADER NULL 'NULL' DELIMITER ' ' CSV;
```

When i run the above code it shows me the following message:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\LENOVO\SQLbook_database\Calendar.txt" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501
```

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` is a server side command. It can only work with files that the user the server runs as has permissions for. For more information see [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) Your choices are to change the file permissions to allow the server user to access it or do as the `HINT:` says and use psql's \copy command [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

**UPDATE**

I don't use pgAdmin much so I forgot, you can also use the [Import/Export Dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.24/import_export_data.html) in pgAdmin).

Comment: i am totally new to postgre sql. can you please elaborately explain the using of psql. how do i open it? how do i connect to my database?

Comment: From Start menu -- All Programs find PostgreSQL 12 and click on it. There should be an entry for SQL Shell(psql). Click on that and fill in or accept the choices to connect. If you are connecting as 'postgres' use the password you created during the install.

Comment: See my UPDATE to answer for a simpler method.